# How to initialize attributes of objects, when creating an array of objects?

Tags: oop

How do I go about initializing attributes of objects, when I create them in an array of objects?

Say, if I would normally do something like:

```
Train train1(unique_id_1,unique_serial_nr_1);
Train train2(unique_id_2,unique_serial_nr_2);
etc...
```

How can I do those initializations, if I want to do an array instead?
I tried something like:

```
Train Trainarray [10] {train1(unique_id_1,unique_serial_nr_1), train2(unique_id_2,unique_serial_nr_2), etc.. }
```

but that doesn't seem to work.
Regards
Anders

Comment: the items should be Train(...)

Comment: Not sure I understand - can you elaborate?

Comment: `Train Trainarray [10] {Train(unique_id_1,unique_serial_nr_1), Train(unique_id_2,unique_serial_nr_2), etc.. }`

Comment: You would attract the right people if you would tag your question with the programming language you are using.